# Openshift Django static files

Tags: django, openshift, static-files

I've started a new Django project for Openshift following the [github example](https://github.com/openshift/django-example).

According to this [openshift post](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/openshift-online-march-2014-release-blog) the project folder structure can be simplified. I tried this so now, I only have `setup.py openshift wsgi.py` files in my repo root. Having this, I tried to serve static files with apache with the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^application/static/(.+)$ /static/$1 [L]
```

But it does not work. It only works if I recreate the wsgi directory and place static folder under it (modifying settings and config files to find them there ofc.).

I guess it is something related with the .htaccess but don't know how to modify it in order to find static files in the repo root folder.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 1):

wsgi.py is the default WSGI entry-point. For backward compatibility, the wsgi/application path is selected as default WSGI entry-point with higher priority. You can customize the path using the OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_WSGI_APPLICATION environment variable.